# Animate Text in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Have anybody experiencing in animating text or characters ? Is it possible to animate characters from the left to right ? In my App i have three dots and i want to animate one by one.

Comment: Its a dot text . But it doesn't matter if it is an image i can change to an image instead of dot.

Answer (score 4):

The UILabel class inherits from [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIView) and can be [implicitly animated](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/AnimatingLayers.html) using animateable properties such as frame, center and bounds.  This means that simply changing these properties results in an animation.